# How to load data dynamically on tab click from controller in spring mvc in same jsp page?

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I am working with Ajax/jquery to reload a division of the page after clicking on a tab, but when I am running the code new jsp is displaying...

JSP page

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up" id="friends">
      <li><a href="/area" data-target="#contacts" class="media_node active span" id="contacts_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Contacts </a></li>
      <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843301/" data-target="#friends_list" class="media_node span" id="friends_list_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Friends list</a></li>
      <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843306/" data-target="#awaiting_request" class="media_node span" id="awaiting_request_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Awaiting request</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="area">
<%@ include file="areas.jsp" %>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="friends_list">
</div>
<div class="tab-pane  urlbox span8" id="awaiting_request">
</div>
</div>
```

ajax call

```
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/area")
public ModelAndView noticesAjaxRequest(ModelMap model) {

    String str="a";

    return new ModelAndView("areas", "str", str);
}
```

But when i am running this code I am only getting areas.jsp as output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you still have `href` attributes in your `<a>` elements.

Change `<a href="/area" ...`

to `<a href="" ...`

You have to store the link in another attribute (e.g. data-href), then.

Comment: You can store the link in another attribute like `data-href`.

Comment: And my controller is correct ?? because i am getting the view which i am returning from controller on my browser or will i have to return something else?

Comment: No, that's fine, because you are inserting the HTML you get from the controller directly into your main page.

Comment: or will the view returned by controller will be placed in the divsion.

Comment: Yes, I think so, that's where `$(targ).html(data);` is for.

Comment: so in division i am including area.jsp should be removed because i am getting view from conroller?

Comment: Yes, but make sure your `data-target` is set to the right div. Right now, it's not.